# Can you be penalized for pleading not guilty if you're found guilty?

Tags: traffic, new-york-state, new-york-city

If you plead not guilty on a traffic ticket in New York City. If at the court hearing you are found guilty, is it possible for them to penalize you or charge you interest for the time elapsed since the incident?

I am referring to penalties/interest in addition to the fine written on the ticket.

Comment: What kind of ticket? Speeding?

Comment: Moving violation

Comment: The reason I ask is there are different types of moving violations and some carry with them varying penalties. I have never heard of fine emanating from a mere ticket being (or having the ability to be) increased for challenging it. @Dale M is correct in that you can end up paying more b/c of fees and surcharges, but the fine itself is constant in any jurisdiction that I've ever practiced. That is not to say it is not possible to have a jurisdiction that allows the judge to impose the maximum fine (if your ticket is for less) if you challenge and lose. This happens in criminal cases.

Comment: It was given for and "improper turn" 1163a

Comment: So,  I've not practiced in New York and cannot answer with an certainty, but I have never heard of this. I do practice in New England and feel i would have heard of this if it was a practice. People may think its increased because of all the additional fees and costs. Often times, when you challenge a ticket you will find the DA will automatically drop it down just because you showed up and spent half a day to deal with it. Also, they often have a hard time getting the cop to testify and they need him/her to testify or else you win.

Comment: You know, reading your question again, there are jurisdictions that require payment of fine before challenging ticket and if you do not, you can either (1) lose ability to challenge; or (2) be assessed interest from the date it was due if you lose. So, maybe that is the case in NY.

Comment: @gracey209: That's interesting you say they have a hard time getting the cop testify. They have a system where I'm from. They somehow manage to schedule each officer's court dates on the same day. So every officer just plans to spend that entire day in court testifying to all the tickets s/he wrote. So they NEVER miss an opportunity to testify where I'm from. (I personally tested that "no-show" theory and "lost" every time.) I guess there's a financial incentive for them to collect money for the city by following through on the back end?

Comment: Oh, that is rough. No, since they plea down almost every ticket, they just call in the cop if someone forces a trial.  But, many times it will be they are busy with actual crimes, days off, etc., so numerous times they cannot get them. It depends a lot on jurisdiction and also on the collective bargaining agreement. A town over, the police get a minimum 4 hours for a court appearance, a minimum 8 for any court appearance over 3 hours, and an owed day of comp time. So, they always show. In Portland, they often will come in b/c their Captain negotiates the tickets (not DA) and calls if try it!

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes. It's called a fine and it will be written on the ticket; that is the penalty for the offence.

Right now you are presumed innocent; you can refute that presumption by paying the fine or you can maintain it and have your day in court. If you defend it and fail then you are guilty **and always were!**

There will be no additional penalties but there may be additional costs. Interest if you pay late, court fees and fees to a lawyer if you hire one.

Just beware that you do not commit the crime of perjury in your defence; you are allowed to be wrong about your innocence, you are not allowed to attempt to pervert the course of justice. [Marcus Einfeld](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcus_Einfeld) serves as a salutary lesson.

Comment: Do you have a source that in New York City, the fine does not increase if you fight the ticket and lose?